# Error putting item in DynamoDB: "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm getting the this error in my Alexa skill

> {
>       "errorMessage": "Converting circular structure to JSON",
>       "errorType": "TypeError",
>       "stackTrace": [
>           "JSON.stringify ()",
>           "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:195:35)",
>           ""
>       ]
>   }

when I try to put an item in my DynamoDB database, here's some of my code:

```
const awsSDK = require('aws-sdk');
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
awsSDK.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
var ddb = new awsSDK.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

and

```
var params = {
TableName:"habits",
Item:{
  "year": "year",
  "title": "title",
  "info":{
      "plot": "Nothing happens at all.",
      "rating": 0
  }
 }
};
```

and

```
return ddb.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak('error')
    .withSimpleCard('Sure', speechText)
    .getResponse();
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speechText)
    .withSimpleCard('Sure', speechText)
    .getResponse();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message you're trying to submit an object that has circular structure. Thus hitting the problem that [JavaScript structures that include circular references can't be serialized with a plain JSON.stringify](https://makandracards.com/makandra/28847-dealing-with-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json-on-javascript).

I would look into your object deeply.

Alternatively you can give [BotTalk](https://bottalk.de) a try. You can create pretty complex Alexa Skills with simple markup language. AND database is included for free.