# AWS Dynamodb Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to **add elements** in a **table** in **dynamodb** like in the example below but when I run it I get this error message: `Missing credentials in the config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`

```
aws.config.update({
   region: "eu-west-1",
   endpoint: "http://localhost:8080",})


  let ddb = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
  });

  let params = {
    TableName: "NameOfTheTable",
    Item: {
      uuid: JSON.stringify(132), // random number for testing
      name: JSON.stringify(req.query.mod), //data i'm passing in
    },
  };

const addMod = ddb.put(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }
});
return res.send(addMod);

});
```

I think probably I'm missing the `accessKeyId` and the `accessSecretKey` but honestly, I did not understand how to set them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you enquire credentials for local because the SDK checks for them, this has been [raised as an issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/880) it seems.

You can get around by specifying any string supposedly. Try the below snippet.

```
aws.config.update({
    region: "eu-west-1",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8080",
    accessKeyId: “xxxxxx”,
    secretAccessKey: “xxxxxx”
});
```

Comment: Hmm seems you have a circular reference somewhere in your codebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json. Do you receive anything back by trying to access the dynamo dB host?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248078/error-putting-item-in-dynamodb-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Comment: I already saw the second question but i did not solve, i don't where the circular reference come from, I also tried passing a string instead of the variable but nothig changed

Comment: It seems that the error is unrelated to this question, I believe it’s the putitem. Might be worth raising as a separate question :)

Comment: as you can see I tried put  in addition to putItems

Comment: If you comment out the put does it run? Just want to limit scope to that function :)

Comment: the only error I get now with "put" is this one:
Error Error [UnknownError]: Not Found
  message: 'Not Found',
  code: 'UnknownError',
  statusCode: 404,

Comment: I also tried with putItems but I get some strange error